# page back button not resetting css

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

I have a button that "navigates" to a new page.

To do this the button makes the current section's/page's display settings = none and the new section/page's display = block.

```
<div class="listLeft"><p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('work')">work</p><p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('about')">about</p></div>
<div class="listRight"><p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('playground')">playground</p><p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('contact')">contact</p></div>
```

js below

```
function navButtons(page) {
  let section = document.getElementById(page);
  section.setAttribute("class", "visible");
  
  window.location.href = `#${page}page`;
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  let pagesArrayCopy = [...pagesArray]
  const unselected = pagesArrayCopy.filter(item => item.id !== page);
  setTimeout(() => {
      unselected.forEach((el, index) => unselected[index].setAttribute("class", "invisible"));
      pagesArray = Array.from(pagesNodeList);
    }, 500);
};
```

when I press the back button the url is obviously changing back to the old #section, but the css doesn't reset, so the new page is still visible and the previous page is still display = none.

How do i get around this, so when the back button is pressed the css values reset to default?

Comment: add your code so we can see what your are doing

Comment: @DCR have added code

Comment: you need to add the rest of your code

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an anchor tag so your URL actually change (ie: update the adress to mypage.html#page2).
Then you could bind a function to [onhashchange](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onhashchange.asp) and check of your page is well displayed.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't supplied all the html. there's no id work so section is null

```js
function navButtons(page) {
  let section = document.getElementById(page);
  console.log(section)
  section.setAttribute("class", "visible");
  
  window.location.href = `#${page}page`;
  window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
  let pagesArrayCopy = [...pagesArray]
  const unselected = pagesArrayCopy.filter(item => item.id !== page);
  setTimeout(() => {
      unselected.forEach((el, index) => unselected[index].setAttribute("class", "invisible"));
      pagesArray = Array.from(pagesNodeList);
    }, 500);
};
```

```html
<div class="listLeft">
   <p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('work')">work</p>
   <p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('about')">about</p></div>
   
<div class="listRight">
<p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('playground')">playground</p>
<p class="listItems" onclick="navButtons('contact')">contact</p></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to bind your changing state to the history of the browser. Since there is no real way of overriding the 'back' button on the browser, you will have to write it into your history. See the History API for HTML5 here:
https://css-tricks.com/using-the-html5-history-api/

The same thing specified above can also be done with this plugin:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/reallysimplehistory/